# Alamofire and SwiftyJSON for Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, alamofire, swifty-json

I am updating my code for Swift 2.0 for today, however the line

`var json = JSON(json)` gives me the following error

> Cannot invoke intializer for type 'JSON' with an argument list of type
>   (Result)

Do you guys have any idea how should I change my code?

```
@IBAction func changePassword(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    Alamofire.request(.POST, AppDelegate.kbaseUrl + "users/me/password", parameters: ["old_password": self.oldPasswordTextField.text!, "new_password": self.newPasswordTextField.text!, "confirm_password": self.confirmPasswordTextField.text!], encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON {
            (req, res, json) in
            var json = JSON(json)
            if json["meta"]["status"]["code"] == 200 {
                self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
            }
            let alert = UIAlertView(title: json["meta"]["msg"]["subj"].stringValue, message: json["meta"]["msg"]["body"].stringValue, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Close")
            alert.show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now the response object came with it so you have to use the `value` property from the response object

So it will be `JSON(json.value!)`

For example :

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/", parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON, headers: nil).responseJSON { (req, res, json) -> Void in
    print("\(res?.allHeaderFields)")
    print("JSON - \(json.value)")

    let swiftJsonVar = JSON(json.value!)
    print(swiftJsonVar)
}
```

Comment: @Happiehappie Welcome anytime.

Comment: @iRealMe Welcome :) You are wanting same question?

Comment: @AshishKakkad Yes, and one more error . May I discuss with you?

Comment: @iRealMe Yes, Anytime.

Comment: great answer ... saved my time ...Thanks

Comment: @i_Looser Welcome :)