# Background Process with request JSON to the server in Swift 2.0

Tags: request, swift2, background-process

I'm trying to create a solution for my app. I need to update information in the background process. The information is required to a server that returns a JSON string.

I found some articles, but all in Object-C, which does not help me much.

But I do not know where to start. I use synchronous or asynchronous request? And to update a list of items without using much memory of iOS? Can anyone help me? Thanks for your answers...

Comment: You can use Alamofire with SwiftyJSON for background process [Stackobverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879264/alamofire-and-swiftyjson-for-swift-2-0/32879734#32879734) and a [Tutorial / Article](http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/10/how-to-use-alamofire-and-swiftyjson-with-swift-swift-2-ios-9-xcode-7/)

Comment: [Good description for Async requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056375/how-to-fetch-and-parse-json-using-swift-2-xcode-7-ios-9/33058743#33058743)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend this open source:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

You can do async request and Parse JSON to an object.
It's very easy to use and developed by a great team. I think it will help you solve your problem.